# How to deploy Python script to a web app?

Tags: python, mysql, frontend, backend

I have a python code that i want to deploy into a website. Until now, I have only used Pycharm, and I have no idea how a website works (I understand some concepts like front-end and back-end). In my research, I tumbled on Django, Flask, MySQL, React, Nodejs, Javascript and many others.

Basically I am lost, after doing a Python Script on Pycharm for example, how do you actually create an app from that code so that other people can use it on a browser? How do you connect the front-end, that will be created with React and Javascript, with a server/database that is written in Python?

I think I understand that the website, created using Django, React, Javascript and others will request information from the server, which will run the actual Python code, but like I said, I am lost on the whole process. I understand I am asking for a lot, but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As i understand you thing too much and trying to learn all together at same time. In my opinion you have to first go Python with Flask (which is very easy) , then connect your python application with other Client Framework like React or Angular etc. After that try to deploy app on server. if you go step by step that all easy for you otherwise all lost same happened to me many time.

Comment: Ask specific you want to know here. so i can help

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will start learning Flask to get familiar with the concepts.

Comment: To host a website, you need to maintain other things other than front-end, back-end.
First, you need a Domain Name and Web Hosting. There are various platforms that help you to get started such as bluehost, bigdaddy.
Then host a server instance (example amazon ec2) that should have a static IP address and would be mapped to the domain name you bought (would be configured in the domain name platform you used).
Then host a web server (such as nginx, apache) on your server instance (on ec2).

Comment: Go through python flask docs and learn how to deploy, connect with third party APIs, connect with databases and proceed.

Comment: Please be specific when asking a question